# ProgressBar stops moving at activity resume using ScrollableTabHost

Tags: android, progress-bar

I use a ProgressBar in one of my activities as this:

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/mProgressBar"
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

My problem is that when I leave the activity (for example press the back button or start a new activity) and return back, the progress bar is shown stopped.

I am using this library (http://code.google.com/p/mobyfactory-uiwidgets-android/) for hosting my activities into a tab host.

I suppose the UI thread pauses, so the progress bar animation stops too. Any ideas how to solve it?